# IPtables to set tcp flags

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp

I am trying to use iptables to modify the tcp flags of outgoing packets.
Is it possible to set tcp flags with iptables? For an incoming SYN, i want it respond with ACK (instead of SYN-ACK).

Comment: How are you interfacing with netfilter/iptables? I don't believe from the command line tools you can do so. If you write a netfilter module you can definitely modify the packets as they traverse (but that is writing code in C)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this? As @dancancode mentioned, this will effectively kill the TCP 3-way handshake.

Comment: @JoelC.. Yeah thats what i want to do. I am basically testing a device behavior when it sends a SYN but in response get an ACK (instead of SYN-ACK)

Comment: So is there a way i can change source ip address of outgoing packets? I have tried the source NAT postrouting in iptables, but it only changes the source ip when my machine is initiating the connection (Sending SYN). It doesnt change if its a response (SYN-ACK)

Answer (score 1):

If it were the MSS or the TCP options you wanted to change, there are extensions to do that, see iptables-extensions(8).  There's nothing there to unset SYN, which makes sense.  Removing the SYN would prevent the three way handshake from completing.  If your goal is to prevent a connection, it's far more straightforward to drop either the incoming SYN packets or the outgoing SYN-ACKs.